# Pandas: Select a value from a choice of three columns and assign as a value in a different column - with pandas apply

Tags: pandas, function, apply

I'm embarrassed to ask this but after 3 days I'm banging my head off the wall.
I have a dataframe with an id and three separate fields eached populated with alternative urls.
I want to choose a url in order of preference (urlA,urlB,urlC) and assign the selected to a new field called chosenUrl.
I have a function that sees if a given url field is populated and if so it returns that url.
I wanted to run this as an apply function in pandas to make it run as fast as possible.
I have done similar applies successfully but every time i run it, it returns a blank. I can't share the actual data set but I've created an anonymised version for reference.

Any idea why it keeps returning blanks?
Code:

```
data = {'id': ['123','456','789'],
        'urlA': ['www.google.com','',''],
    'urlB': ['','www.amazon.com',''],
    'urlC': ['','','www.yahoo.com']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','urlA','urlB','urlC'])

#function to select populated url - does the string contain a '.'?
def selectUrl(urlA,urlB,urlC):
    tmp = '.'
    if tmp in str(urlA):
        y= urlA
    elif tmp in str(urlB):
        y = urlB
    elif tmp in str(urlC):
        y= urlC
    else:
        y = ''
    return y

#Pandas apply statement
df['selectedURL']=df.apply(lambda x: selectUrl(x['urlA'],x['urlB'],x['urlB']), axis=1)
```

I would expect this to return

[image]

Any ideas? I was thinking that maybe its returning an object of the whole field which is ignored but haven't been able to figure it out. I have no doubt i'm going to facepalm after someone points something out but I will deserve it!

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because here is prioritize column `urlA`, then `urlB` and last `urlC` select this columns by priority in list (first are more prioritized), then replace empty strings to missing values, back filling missing values and fill first column by position:

```
df['url'] = df[['urlA','urlB','urlC']].replace('',np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
    id            urlA            urlB           urlC             url
0  123  www.google.com                                 www.google.com
1  456                  www.amazon.com                 www.amazon.com
2  789                                  www.yahoo.com   www.yahoo.com
```

Importance of order of values of list is possible see in changed data:

```
data = {'id': ['123','456','789'],
        'urlA': ['www.google.com','www.google.com',''],
    'urlB': ['','www.amazon.com','www.amazon.com'],
    'urlC': ['www.yahoo.com','','www.yahoo.com']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','urlA','urlB','urlC'])

#A,B,C priority
df['url1'] = df[['urlA','urlB','urlC']].replace('',np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
#C,B,A priority
df['url2'] = df[['urlC','urlB','urlA']].replace('',np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
    id            urlA            urlB           urlC            url1  \
0  123  www.google.com                  www.yahoo.com  www.google.com   
1  456  www.google.com  www.amazon.com                 www.google.com   
2  789                  www.amazon.com  www.yahoo.com  www.amazon.com   

             url2  
0   www.yahoo.com  
1  www.amazon.com  
2   www.yahoo.com
```